# Kotin sort by descending then ascending

Tags: sorting, kotlin, collections

Im trying to order a list on multiple parameters..  for example, one value descending, second value ascending, third value descending.

```
 var people = listOf<People>(People("palazo", "ooo", 1),
            People("asdf", "cccc", 2),
            People("Maria", "ooo", 3),
            People("Helena", "ccccc", 3),
            People("Carlos", "ccc", 4),
            People("Jhon", "ooo", 2)
    )
```

is there a way like this to do it?  (i know is incorrect)
people = people.sortedByDescending { it.name}.thenBy{it.lastname}.thenDescending{it.age}

or add to :

```
   people.sortedWith(compareBy(People::name, People::lastName)) 
   //but mixing ascending and descending
```

Comment: What you want to achieve? Can you elaborate more and provide some more model data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val sortedPeople = people.sortedWith(
    compareByDescending(People::name)
        .thenBy(People::lastName)
        .thenByDescending(People::age)
)
```